# Java subtract values in HashMaps by key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, subtraction

I need some help, I'm learning by myself how to deal with maps in Java and  today I was trying to get the subtraction of the values from a Hashmap via key but now I am stuck.

These are the map values that I want to subtract (arithmetic subtraction between the values with keys ).

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1, "10");
map.put(2, "5");
```

In the below i want to subtract by key like

```
 (key1) - (key2) = 5
```

Comment: If you want to do arithmetic on the values, why are you storing them as Strings?

Comment: ok i will correct this

Comment: You should be using `Map<Integer, Integer>`. Then the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to parse those strings into Integer first. This is because you are storing values as `String` on which arithmetic operations cannot be performed.

```
Integer.parseInt(map.get(1)) - Integer.parseInt(map.get(2))
```

Alternative you can store values as integers like this.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
map.put(1, 10);
map.put(2, 5);
```

and perform below

```
map.get(1) - map.get(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first parse the string into integer and then substract it.

It goes like :-

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(map.get(1)) - Integer.parseInt(map.get(2))
```